# TypeError : 'undefined' is not an object

Tags: javascript

I have a shout box on my Joomla site that is producing this error.

This is the Error:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'config['show_photos']')
```

And javascript code is:

```
    function prepareShout(json, config, permissions, data)
{
    html  = '<div class="shoutbox-row" id="shout-' + json['s_id'] + '">';
    html += '<div class="shoutbox-member">';

    if (config['show_photos'])
    {
        if (json['s_mid'] != 0)
        {       
            if (config['profiles'])
            {
                html += '<a class="shoutbox-avatar" href="' + json['s_avatar']['link'] + '" title="' + data['ptitle'] + '"><img src="' + json['s_avatar']['image'] + '"></a>';
            }
            else
            {
                html += '<span class="shoutbox-avatar"><img src="' + json['s_avatar']['image'] + '"></span>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            html += '<span class="shoutbox-avatar"><img src="' + json['s_avatar']['image'] + '"></span>';
        }           
}
```

Is it possible to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

just confirm your `config` object has a value as well like this

```
 if (config && config['show_photos'])
 ...

 if (config && config['profiles']){
 ...
```

Comment: Firebug says there is an error on line 6: if (config['show_photos'])
How to deal with it?

Comment: @user3216677 weird that is also on my post, probably you need to refresh

Comment: Now i have started getting this error:
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jQuery("#shout-" + json['s_id']).effect("highlight", {color: "#e1f5df"}, 3000)') success (smartshoutbox.js, line 94) c (jquery.min.js, line 4) fireWith (jquery.min.js, line 4) k (jquery.min.js, line 6) r (jquery.min.js, line 6)